# How to Read equations from word document in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have a Table Inside Word and I am fetching the equation from the word but it is considering equation as texts. I get equation as f(x)={■(x^2,&x≥0@x^2 |x|,&x<0) in code. I have given below the code where I am looping through the word document paragraphs and the image of my word document

```
 private string ExtractContentWithImages(WordprocessingDocument doc, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.TableCell cell)
    {
        StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var paragraph in cell.Elements<Paragraph>())
        {
            foreach (var equation in paragraph.Descendants<OfficeMath>())
            {
                string equationText = GetEquationFromOMath(equation);
                contentBuilder.AppendLine(equationText);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(paragraph.InnerText))
            {
                // This is a text paragraph, process text
                string lineText = paragraph.InnerText;
                contentBuilder.Append(lineText);
            }
        }

        return contentBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

[Image of word Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkOpK.png)

Comment: Could you clarify what format you want the equations to be in after extraction?
in the word example you showed the format is in OMath XML, some other used formats for equations are LaTeX or MathML for which you could use some external library like OpenXML2TeX or MathType SDK

Comment: the equation is text, but you THEN have to set a font for the equation. If you look close, the equations use a font called Cambria Math. You can rename a .docx with a .zip file extension, and then open the zip file - all of word is in fact xml, and you can by re-naming the .docx to .zip, and you see the font table. So, formula's are stored as text, and they look "pretty" due to the correct font being used.

Comment: We are developing a website from which users can upload multiple-choice questions using a Word document from the admin panel, and these questions will then be visible on the website and apps. However, when equations are included in the document, they are displayed as 'f(x)={■(x^2,&x≥0@x^2 |x|,&x<0)', which is not readable for the average user. Therefore, I want them to be displayed in the format shown in the first equation of the image. Is there any way to convert them to that format? Thank you in advance.